# question about mesh rotation

Tags: transforms, axis

is there a way for the rotation widget to be affected by rotation? In the pictures, I have the same mesh but one is rotated 90d on axis. I want the rotation widget *red green blue lines* to turn with my mesh so I can do rotations easier. the picture emphasizes the staticness of the widget which I want to change.

Answer (score 5):

The widget is static because your orientation is set to "world"-- and your world isn't rotating.  Its X, Y and Z axes are always oriented the same way.

If you want the widget to change rotation to match your object, you want a different orientation-- probably, "local."  When you use that orientation, the widget's axes represent the axes of your object, not the world, and those axes change with rotation.

[image]

Notice the tooltip.

Comment: Thank you! simple fix!